# How to make this beautiful and short

Tags: ruby

```
filename = filename.gsub("_"," ").nil? ? filename.gsub("_"," ") : filename
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
filename = filename.gsub("_", " ")
```

Or if it's ok to mutate the string:

```
filename.gsub!("_", " ")
```

Checking whether `gsub` returns nil is completely unnecessary - `gsub` never returns `nil`. `gsub!` returns `nil` if no changes have been made, but if you use `gsub!`, you usually don't care about the return value anyway.

Also note that the code you gave will always return `filename` unchanged because you mixed up the `then`- and the `else`-part of your `?:`.

Comment: Ruby Documentation says: Performs the substitutions of String#gsub in place, returning str, or nil if no substitutions were performed

Comment: @auralbee: You're mixing up `gsub!` and `gsub`. You quoted the documentation for `gsub!`, but you used `gsub` in your code. `gsub` never returns `nil`, `gsub!` does.

Answer (score 0):

basically, just

```
filename.gsub!("_", " ")
```

Or alternatively,

```
filename = filename.split("_").join(" ")
```